# bool(false) does not show any result on VSCode(Python)

Tags: python, boolean

so very new here trying to learn python.
I code using VS Code. I also changed in the JSON file to give me only the output on Debug Console.
My issue is that I try to run:

```
bool(False)
bool("123")
```

and stuff like that but when i run the code it should show false and true. The problem is that VS returns nothing, literally blank. but when I type:

```
print(bool("Hello"))
```

i am getting a result, thank you.